# FIFA Scenario Logic

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, logic, game-engine, game-physics

I always wondered about FIFA's (game) logic.

Do they rely on lots of if statements for game rules and other ruley things?

Like:

```
if( ball.x > areaLeft.x || ball.y > areaTop.y ) {
     out();
}

if( playersCollision > 100 ) {
    giveFoul(firstPlayer, secondPlayer);
}
```

etc.. Is everything really "if" for such things or is there other alternatives to this?

Comment: In a word, no. Have a look at sprites

Comment: Unless someone from FIFA can chime in, I don't think that this question can get a definite, concrete answer here.  There are a lot of techniques useful for modeling systems like these, and without knowing which one they've used I doubt that you can get a definitive answer.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I am curious what you mean by *sprites* in the context of game logic.

Comment: What would you propose as an alternative to `if` for testing conditions?

Comment: There are always *ifs* in the equation. The thing is it's less simple than your algorithm... mainly because it's not decided by a computer but by one or more human beings...

Comment: Well not just the bat moving up and donw the screen more the way you'd drive that.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely not "if"s. That would be a mess.
[Expert systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system) were made to deal with cases like these, where you want to maintain a knowledge base that is subject to complex rules.
The idea is, you write a set of rules using a logic-based language. E.g.

```
giveFoul(Context) :- 
    closePlayers(Context, A, B),
    attackingPlayer(context, A, B),
    defendingSkills(A, ASkill),
    ASkill < 80
    ...

closePlayers(Context, A, B) :-
    position(Context, A, CoordXA, CoordYA),
    position(Context, B, CoordXB, CoordYB),
    ...
```

You can see that using this approach you can change the behaviour of your system by redefining these rules and let your inference system do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

There are always *ifs* in the equation. The thing is it's less simple than the algorithm suggested, mainly because it's not decided by a computer but by one or more human beings... [esp. FIFA since they don't want to implement arbitration based on video]

Anyway it would be more like

```
 // x in [0,99], the higher x is, the more probable the event is
 function fate(x) {
    return (random () % 100) <= x)
 }

 // if ball out, 75% chance there is an out event
 if( (ball.x > areaLeft.x || ball.y > areaTop.y) && fate(75) ) {
   out();
 }

 // if there is a collision, 50% chance the referee gives a foul 
 if( playersCollision > 100 && fate(50)) {
   giveFoul(firstPlayer,secondPlayer);
 }

etc....
```